# PHP Mail never reach target

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send mail using the built in mail function.
However the mail never reaches its reciever.

This is the output in mail.log, notice I've changed my real domain to mydomain.com

```
Mar 21 11:15:42 localhost sendmail[30741]: s2LAFgnJ030741: from=www-data, size=2138, 
class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201403211015.s2LAFgnJ030741@mydomain.com>, relay=www-data@localhost

Mar 21 11:15:42 localhost sm-mta[30742]: s2LAFgsJ030742: from=<www-data@mydomain.com>, size=2419, 
class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201403211015.s2LAFgnJ030741@mydomain.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]


Mar 21 11:15:42 localhost sendmail[30741]: s2LAFgnJ030741: to=foo@mydomain.com, ctladdr=www-data (33/33), 
delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=32138, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (s2LAFgsJ030742 Message accepted for delivery)

Mar 21 11:15:42 localhost sm-mta[30744]: s2LAFgsJ030742: to=<foo@mydomain.com>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, 
mailer=esmtp, pri=122419, relay=spamfilter.spam.com. [xx.xx.xx.xx], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable

Mar 21 11:15:42 localhost sm-mta[30744]: s2LAFgsJ030742: s2LAFgsJ030744: DSN: Service unavailable

Mar 21 11:15:42 localhost sm-mta[30744]: s2LAFgsJ030744: to=<www-data@mydomain.com>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, 
mailer=esmtp, pri=30000, relay=spamfilter.spam.com., dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable

Mar 21 11:15:42 localhost sm-mta[30744]: s2LAFgsJ030744: s2LAFgsK030744: return to sender: Service unavailable

Mar 21 11:15:42 localhost sm-mta[30744]: s2LAFgsK030744: to=foo, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=30000, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

**Relevant lines in my PHP.INI**

SMTP = XX.XX.XX.XX <- verified it does work with PHPMailer.

SMTP_PORT = 25

sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

If you look at the mail error above, what could cause this? I know that there is an exception at the spamfilter for mydomain.com.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you configured the mail server perfectly to work on loacalhost??

Comment: How can I verify this? I am not sure I have.

Comment: It looks like it's blocked by a spam filter. Maybe some information (headers) are missing, causing the e-mail to be rejected.

Comment: you can check my answer,and veryfy the configurations,and let me know what you found,may be further i could help

Comment: We have our own SMTP and we run nginx on debian.

Answer (score 0):

Ok configuration for the mail to work **locally** would go like this then
You can send mail from localhost with sendmail package , sendmail package is provided with XAMPP by default. So if you are using XAMPP then you can easily send mail from localhost.

For example you can configure `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` and `c:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini` for gmail to send mail.

In `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` find `extension=php_openssl.dll` and remove the semicolon from the beginning of that line to make SSL working for gmail for localhost.

```
In `php.ini` file find `[mail function]` and change
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = my-gmail-id@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

Now Open C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini. Replace all the existing code in sendmail.ini with following code

```
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=my-gmail-id@gmail.com
auth_password=my-gmail-password
force_sender=my-gmail-id@gmail.com
```

Now you are done!! create php file with mail function and send mail from localhost.

PS: don't forgot to replace my-gmail-id and my-gmail-password in above code with your id and password. Also, don't forget to remove duplicate keys if you copied settings from above. For example comment following line if there is another sendmail_path : `sendmail_path="C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"` in the `php.ini` file